# android Collapsingtoolbarlayout show full text when needed

Tags: android, title, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Hi I have an android app using Collapsingtoolbarlayout. the title of the Collapsingtoolbarlayout will be the title of the article from previous activity/fragment (how can I make the Collapsingtoolbarlayout to display full title (resize font, take additional space) when needed?

Currently, Iam using these code. How to modify the code to display title correctly? any help is much appreciate. Thanks

```
Activity activity = this.getActivity();
        CollapsingToolbarLayout appBarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        if (appBarLayout != null) {
            appBarLayout.setTitle(topStory.getTitle());
            appBarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(View.NO_ID);
            appBarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
            appBarLayout.setTitleEnabled(true);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the text size you need to add this to your CollapsingToolbarLayout:

```
   app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
```

Or in Java:

```
mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getTitle());
mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(android.R.stlye.);
mCollapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(android.R.style.);
```

To dynamically fit the size to the article layout you have two options:
You set the textSize to a size, which will allow every possible title to appear completely (If you already know each titles)

Or you check how many Characters the title has and change the textAppeareance of the CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: hi thanks for your response. Can we make title to be 2 line instead of only one? because my title is different base on each artitcle

Comment: maybe this library helps : https://github.com/opacapp/multiline-collapsingtoolbar

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't believe that four years later I'm still struggling to get `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to handle this. Specifically, we need the height of the expanded `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to wrap the size of the expanded title without any contained image or other content.

In order to achieve this I had to create a fake `TextView` within the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to mimic the appearance and content of the expanded title, so that the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` calculates its expanded height based upon it. This `TextView` remains invisible so that we can still use the animation provided by `CollapsingToolbarLayout` between its collapsed and expanded titles.

Here's the XML for you to use:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:liftOnScroll="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/OmegaHeadingMedium"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/spacer_small"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="@dimen/spacer_grid"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/spacer_grid"
        app:expandedTitleMarginTop="?actionBarSize"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/OmegaHeadingLarge"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        app:maxLines="3"
        tools:title="Title">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:titleMarginEnd="@dimen/spacer_small" />

        <!-- This title is used to dynamically calculate the height
            of the collapsing toolbar. Styling should match that of
            the expanded title appearance. -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_fake_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/spacer_grid"
            android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacer_xsmall"
            android:textAppearance="@style/OmegaHeadingLarge"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            tools:text="Really really really really really really really really long title"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

(Keep in mind that styles, dimensions, and other properties in that XML is just for demonstration)

Here's how you would then use it in Kotlin:

```
collapsing_toolbar.title = "Title"
txt_fake_title.text = "Title"
```